# Mirroring of OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

I am working on a map rendering application and would like to hook it up to a current GIS database to get shapefiles and other data. One possible data resource I have looked at is [OpenStreetMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStreetMap). For my application I would want to have the data locally for processing, so I would need to mirror the database. I know that I can get a dump of the whole database, but ideally I would like to get dynamic updates to my dump as the data is improved; hence I am looking for more like a mirroring functionality. Does OpenStreetMap allow for their whole database to be locally mirrored by users, or does it only allow localized queries?

Answer (score 3):

You can have raw OSM data in a database, even for regional extracts, and then apply daily, hourly or minutely updates via small diff files.

See the OSM wiki about [planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) and its section about "Update frequency".

Tools mentioned there are osmosis or OSMupdate.

Or see help.osm.org about "[How to maintain a local copy of a specific area of the OSM database](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/42740/how-to-maintain-a-local-copy-of-a-specific-area-of-the-osm-database)"